# What is the difference between the different types of bank in Canada?

Tags: canada, banking, regulation

In Canada banks are referred to as tier 1 and tier 2.  What are the differences between them?  What services are they allowed to offer and not offer?  Are all covered by the CDIC?

Answer (score 3):

The "Tier 1" banks in Canada are much like the "[Original Six](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_Six)" for the NHL - they were created a long, long time ago, and the definition will (probably) never change :)

Specifically, they are:

1. Royal Bank (RBC)
2. Toronto-Dominon (TD)
3. Bank of Nova Scotia (BNS)
4. Bank of Montreal (BMO)
5. Canadian Imperial Bank of Commerce (CIBC)

"Tier 2" is everyone else There are some more well-known ones like ING, National Bank, and HSBC.

They are all covered by the CDIC (except for credit unions / caisses populaires). For some reason the fin.gc.ca site is down right now so I'll update this post more tomorrow.

[Update]: Wow they are having issues; search page is completely broken now.

Comment: You only listed five. :)

Comment: The original six are NHL teams, not banks. I think the point is that for many folks, these are the only teams that matter.

Comment: By analogy with the NHL 'original six' I presume that means the Tier 1 banks are old and venerable, but that there is no actual legal difference between them and the Tier 2 banks. Is that right?

Comment: @DJClayworth that's correct.